# Where is the Pitstop page and why is it so hard to find?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Where is the Pitstop page for Motor Vehicle Repair and why is it so hard to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually really easy to find ... *if you know where to look* (I guess :o).

Go to the top ribbon bar and left click on the upper left twiddle which says "StackExchange" (in white, then blue letters). In the menu which appears, click on the link for "Chat". That will open a secondary page which will have a listing of chat rooms for MVM&R. Then click on [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) ... (or just click this link).

Comment: I see no chat option in the list?

Comment: To the right of the list at the top. Says "Chat".

Comment: Ah, I found it, thanks!

Comment: Stack exchange icon No longer works to find it?

Comment: @Moab - Use the top right icon in the black ribbon. You can find the link there. Or you can click on the link above in my answer :o) Good to see you, BTW.